# Determining if a page is a static .aspx page or does not exist in the sitecore pipeline

Tags: sitecore, pipeline

I'm working in the Sitecore pipeline on a processor. I need to determine if a request being sent is for a static `.aspx` page that does not have a context item or if the page being requested does not exist.

This will happen right after the `ItemResolver` process fires so the database is set to `master` for both an `.aspx` running through the pipeline and a request for a page that doesn't exist.

I can't check if the `Context.Item == null` because the static page has no item associated with it and I'd like to keep it that way since the content on said page will not be changing.

Let me know if you have any ideas to differentiate between these!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use `Sitecore.Context.Page.FilePath`. It will be set to your `Layout` on a Sitecore item (i.e. '/layouts/standard layout.aspx') while on a static page it'll be the path to your page.

If your static pages are all in a different location from your Sitecore layouts it might be as easy as just matching part of the `FilePath`.

Comment: Woah nice! Just a quick note Context.Page.FilePath is set to "" right after ItemResolver if a sitecore item is being used. The weird thing is that static .aspx pages have a path while a request sent out to /doesntexist.aspx is set to "" just like the FilePath of an item. To filter out existing .aspx pages and pages that have items all you need to do is check if(Context.Item || Context.Page.FilePath != ""). I feel like this may blow up on me so I'm going to test it a bit and then update this comment. Let me know if you see any hazards and thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that Context.Page.FilePath will also be blank if the item doesn't have any layout details assigned. In this case you may still want a 404, but something to be aware of.

Comment: That's something I didn't think of. Thanks for the heads up. I'm going to try to have that case 404 unless it is an image that exists in sitecore (won't have presentation details but I want sc to handle and display it).

Answer (score 2):

I think you partially answered your own question.

If you put a component in the httpBeginRequest pipeline after ItemResolver, you should be able to check if `Context.Item == null`. If it is `null`, then you know the URL doesn't resolve to a Sitecore item. At that point you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()` to see if it resolves to a path. If it does, then you know it's a static .aspx file. Something like:

```
public class CheckPath : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null)
        {
            if (args.Context.Server.MapPath(args.Context.Request.RawUrl) == null)
            {
                // 404
            }
            else
            {
                // Static
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            // Sitecore item
        }
    }
}
```

Patch this into the httpBeginRequest Pipeline:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="MyNamespace.CheckPath, MyAssemblyName" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In this situation is there a difference between checking if Sitecore.Context.Page.FilePath == "" and args.Context.Server.MapPath(args.Context.Request.RawUrl) == null?

Comment: Yes there is a big difference. In this code, you are checking "did ItemResolver resolve an item". If not, then you see if IIS resolved an ASPX page.  At the point we check Server.MapPath, Sitecore.Context.Page will be null and throw a NullRef exception.